# Raspi Servo is jittery and moves back and forth when it should be still

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, servo

(Sorry about formatting)
I am trying to write an opencv program to track the color red.
So far it works okay, but the servo is jittery and when the object is still and centre the servo moves back and forth. I have a 470uf capacitor and an external power supply. Any help to make it smoother would be a godsend!

'''

```
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray 
from picamera import PiCamera
import time 
import cv2
import numpy as np
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time


###SERVO SETUP###
servoPIN_x = 17
servoPIN_y = 18
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(servoPIN_x, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(servoPIN_y, GPIO.OUT)
px = GPIO.PWM(servoPIN_x, 50)
py = GPIO.PWM(servoPIN_y, 50)
position_x = 7.5
position_y = 7.5
px.start(position_x)
py.start(position_y)

x_gain = 0.1#0.01 - 5.00
y_gain = 0.3#0.01 - 5.00

xon = True
yon = True

###CAMERA SETUP##
camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (640, 480)
camera.framerate = 32
raw_capture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(640, 480))
time.sleep(0.1)


###VIDEO CAPTURE LOOP### 
for frame in camera.capture_continuous(raw_capture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
    #cv2 video init
    image = frame.array
    hsv_frame = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
#color parameters
low_red = np.array([161,155,84])
high_red = np.array([179,255,255])

#find color
red_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_frame, low_red, high_red)#create black/white mask for all reds
contours,_ = cv2.findContours(red_mask,cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)#find different red contours
contours = sorted(contours, key=lambda x:cv2.contourArea(x), reverse=True)#sort contours from largest to smallest

#set line x/y var to center
x_medium=320
y_medium=240

#loop sets x/y_medium
for cnt in contours:
    (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    y_medium = int((y+y+h)/2)
    x_medium = int((x+x+w)/2)
    cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
    break

#draw lines
cv2.line(image,(x_medium,0),(x_medium,480), (0,255,0),2)
cv2.line(image,(0,y_medium),(640,y_medium), (0,255,0),2)

#cv2.imshow('mask', red_mask)
#show regular frame
cv2.imshow("Frame", image)
key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
raw_capture.truncate(0)

#quit 
if key == ord("q"):
    cv2.waitKey(1)
    px.stop()
    py.stop
    break



#servoX travels to place postion_x in center frame
if not xon and x_medium != 320:
    px.start(position_x)


if x_medium > 320:
    position_x = position_x - x_gain
    
elif x_medium < 320:
    position_x = position_x + x_gain
elif x_medium == 320:
    position_x = position_x
    xon = False
else:
    position_x = 7.5
    
if xon:
    px.ChangeDutyCycle(position_x)
else:
    px.stop



px.stop()
py.stop()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
exit(0)
```

'''

Comment: We don't handle hardware issues on Stack Overflow, but let me guess: it is one of these very cheep servos?

Comment: You might get better answers over on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/. In my experience, the software PWM (e.g. as implemented by GPIO.PWM) is pretty crappy and always results in jitter. Use a better pwm solution (the Pi supports two hardware PWM channels) and things may improve.

Comment: Maybe you could give the position control a larger dead band, e.g. compare with <318 and >322 and just an else condition to set xon to false (as the current else should never happen)?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with this kind of servo motors while building a robot. I solved it using another library called "pigpio", to control the pins of the rasperry pi . Since then the servos no longer move for no reason.  The commands are very similar. Have a look at:

> http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/